# Dashboard Summary on Memberships Page

Tags: civimember, permissions, acl

I've just found out that the Membership Dashboard - specifically the summary table at the top of that page - is not visible if you don't have the permission 'CiviCRM: view all contacts'. Is there any way around this?

We've just implemented ACLs on a site and the staff member looking after memberships would like the dashboard back...

Comment: other way 'around it' (if using drupal) would be to make a drupal view and offer that to the user as the Dashboard instead

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to implement this for the time being but see whether the client is interested in getting someone on board to fix it 'properly'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a hardcoded limitation in CiviCRM, and changing that would require some development work (i.e., there's no workaround or trick to it, just needs code changes).

Interestingly, there's a comment in the code that indicates a desire to add support for ACLs instead of the sledgehammerish 'view all contacts' requirement: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Member/Page/DashBoard.php#L51

So my answer would be: yes, you're seeing it right; there's no way around this short of patching core, and it sounds like core is willing to be patched.

Comment: Thanks @TwoMice for confirming, and useful to know the comment exists!